# How to remove a class via JavaScript (NOT jQuery) at Wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, html

I need your help at a problem of my Wordpress Webpage. My Wordpress-page is an Single-Page-App with 3 different boxes of content. The left and center boxes are static, the right one changes its content by clicking on links of the other boxes. I decided, to load all the content in the right box and show them with the CSS-command visibility. With a combination of pathJS and JS,  i want the URL to change by clicking on the links. So far so good - all works fine, but i dont get managed via my JS-Function to remove the shown-class.

My script looks like this:

```
<script>
           function showDetailContent(showid) {
                //suche objekt right_id -> was du zeigen willst -> getelementbyid
    alert("1");            
    var id = document.getElementsByClassName('shown');
                alert("2");
                id.classList.remove('shown');
                alert("3");
                document.getElementByID("right_" + showid).classList.add('shown');
                alert("4");
           }
//var c = document.getElementById('content'); -->do the function :)
           Path.map("#/?p=<?php the_id();?>").to(function () {   
                showDetailContent(<?php the_id();?>);
           });
           Path.listen();
       </script>
```

The alerts are just my way of "debugging". I think its not the best way to debugg, but i am very new in the world of prorgamming and this is kind of easy.
However, the first two alerts are shown, if i activate a link. So the (first) mistake is on the line

```
id.classList.remove('shown');
```

Normally, the right-box is hidden, so that only one content is load.
Do you understand my problem till here?
I would appreciate fast help!
Greetings, Yannic! :)

Comment: to remove a class I would suggest taking a look at the classname property and the replace method

Comment: you can use this `document.querySelector('.shown').classList.remove('shown');`

Comment: `var test = document.querySelectorAll('.pln');
for(i=0;i<test.length;i++){ test[i].classList.add('foo');}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this : http://snipplr.com/view/3561/ to know remove class pure javascript

Comment: Oh man. Why did not I find this page when i was searching for an answer. Thanks alot! :)

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` gets multiple elements, try:

```
var id = document.getElementsByClassName('shown')[0];
```

Or iterate through them if you want to remove class from all elements with class shown;

Comment: Works great!
Thanks for the really fast help. Have a nice weekend!